# find is using a LOT of resources - how do I find out why?

Tags: 12.04, find, memory-usage

My Ubuntu 12.04 LTS system has been running very slow lately.  I keep having to reboot it, and then within 24 hours it's slowed down again.  I've gone in and run top and what keeps coming up at the top of my resource usage is ***find***.  I have no idea what it's doing, or why it's even running, but it seems to start on it's own.  This has been consistent over the past couple weeks, every time I reboot.  Any idea what's causing this, or how I can stop it from happening?

Here's a partial dump from top:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND     
17721 root      21   1 1685m 1.6g  768 D    0 20.6   1:22.03 find               
14136 homeserv  20   0 1586m 236m 4260 S    0  3.0  16:35.70 mono               
 5928 homeserv  20   0 1350m 185m  11m S    7  2.3  51:31.56 vino-server        
 7701 subsonic  20   0 2533m 139m 2200 S    0  1.8  12:24.58 java
```

Thanks for the help!!

Ed

Comment: Have you tried to kill the process?

Comment: You may be able to use [`pstree`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/pstree.1.html) to discover what process is executing `find`. Does that reveal anything?

Comment: Does it always slow down around the same time?  Do you run updatedb ([locate](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man8/updatedb.8.html)) via cron?  Are there any disk errors?

Comment: You could also use something like `ps -ef | grep [f]ind` or `ps -eo cmd= | grep [f]ind` to see the full commandline/arguments that it's being run with - that should help narrow down the source.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how to kill the find process - I read the man page but it's focused on how to use it, not how to kill it (I'm more of a casual Ubuntu user, as you can tell)...

Comment: It always slows around the same time, and I don't believe I'm running updatedb, but I have several server apps that run - greyhole, Plex, nzbdrone - apps that index the contents of the drives.  It's possible those run updatedb?

Comment: I ran the ps command and got this:

`root     17760 17576  0 06:30 ?        00:00:00 sh -c find -L /var/spool/greyhole -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n 2> /dev/null | head -9994686
root     17761 17760  1 06:30 ?        00:00:03 find -L /var/spool/greyhole -type f -printf %T@ %p?n`

The second ps command resulted in this: 

`sh -c find -L /var/spool/greyhole -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n 2> /dev/null | head -9994686
find -L /var/spool/greyhole -type f -printf %T@ %p?n`

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out the find command was being executed by the [greyhole spool process](https://github.com/gboudreau/Greyhole/issues/123).  I'm not quite sure how I will resolve it yet, since I use greyhole extensively on over 14TB of storage, but at least I know what the cause is.